# QGIS issue 20381 (freezes when data source manager is used) but on PC running Windows 10

Tags: qgis, windows-10

I am having an issue where QGIS (both 3.4 and 3.10) where it freezes every time I try to use the data source manager. I have found the [issue and solution](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20381), however the work around is for people running MacOS and I am running Windows 10.

I have tried to find the app permissions, but am not seeing the advanced options tab associated with QGIS that would be required to fix the issue. I click on Apps> Apps & Features> I find QGIS, but my only option is to uninstall. I have tried turning off permissions for all apps, tried uninstalling and reinstalling, and tried uninstalling 3.4 and installing 3.10. I feel like I am so close to the solution, but just can't get there.